# Что такое изменяемость http метода POST в HttpServlet?

Tags: java, servlet

В различных [статьях (одна из таких)](http://javastudy.ru/interview/jee-servlet-api-questions/) упоминается понятие изменяемость и неизменяемость `http` методов и говориться о том что `POST` единственный изменяемый.

> HTTP метод называется неизменяемым, если он всегда возвращает
>   одинаковый результат. HTTP методы GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
>   являются неизменяемыми. Необходимо реализовывать приложение так, чтобы
>   эти методы возвращали одинаковый результат. К изменяемым методам
>   относится HTTP метод POST. Post метод используется для реализации
>   чего-либо, что изменяется при каждом запросе.

Вот я не могу понять `чего-либо` это что на пример может быть?

Comment: Ответы сервера, на выполнение метода POST, не кэшируются.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это значит, что сколько раз не отправляй запрос GET, если сервер правильно реализует стандарт HTTP, возвращаться всегда будет один и тот же результат. Но отправка запроса POST должна обязательно приводить к изменению данных на стороне сервера и, соответственно, различному ответу. Только относится всё это не только к сервлетам, а в целом к реализации протокола HTTP.